# Best Way to implement Email generation in this scheduled console app

Tags: c#, console-application, email-attachments, email

I have never programmatically generated and sent email notifications before.  What I need to do is this, if this program fails to move files or encounters an exception to generate an email and (preferably) attach a Log.txt file to the email then send it. This app will be ran from an enterprise scheduler and ran 1/hour to manage the files and folders.

Here is the functional code that I currently have (no email implementation exists yet) I have commented in the locations that I would like to send an email

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace FileOrganizer
{
   class Program
   {
      //These are the folder to organize and delimeter that is in the filenames to split off a folder from
      static string folder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["folder"]; //"C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\Organize Me"
      static string delim = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["delim"]; // delim = "__"

      //location for the log.txt file
      static string logPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logPath"]; //C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\Log.txt

      //contact list from the app.config
      static string emailTo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["notifyEmailAddress"]; //multiple email addresses delimited by a ; example = tom@domain.com;dick@differentDomain.com;harry@domain.com

      //for the log.txt reporting
      static int filesMoved = 0;
      static int filesNOTmoved = 0;
      static string fileNamesNOTmoved = "";
      static int foldersCreated = 0;
      static string message = "";
      static string stackTrace = "";
      //used for passing all the objects into the log method
      static object[] details = new object[6];

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         try
         { 
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(logPath))
            {
               int total = organizeFolder(delim, folder);
               details[0] = filesMoved;
               details[1] = filesNOTmoved;
               details[2] = fileNamesNOTmoved;
               details[3] = foldersCreated;
               details[4] = "No Errors Found";
               details[5] = "No Errors Found";
               Log(details, w);
               if (filesNOTmoved > Convert.ToInt32(filesNOTmoved))
               {
                  //generate email to notify of filesNames not moved (prefer to send Log.txt as attachment)
               }
            }
            using (StreamReader r = File.OpenText(logPath))
            {
               DumpLog(r);
            }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(logPath))
            {
               details[0] = filesMoved;
               details[1] = filesNOTmoved;
               details[2] = fileNamesNOTmoved;
               details[3] = foldersCreated;
               details[4] = ex.Message.ToString();
               details[5] = ex.StackTrace.ToString();
               Log(details, w);
            }
            //generate email to notify of Error and (prefer to send Log.txt as attachment)
            using (StreamReader r = File.OpenText(logPath))
            {
               DumpLog(r);
            }
         }   
      }   

      /*Takes a folder and organizes it into folder by naming folder whatever 
       * is in front of the delimeter Example -->(folderName__fileName.txt would be moved 
       * to a new or existing folder named folderName.  Final path for file would 
       * look like this folderName\folderName__fileName.txt)
       * 
       * It will not move file if it already exists in the new location, instead
       * it prompts user that they should rename file and run program again.*/
       static int organizeFolder(string delimeter, string rootPath)
       {
          //counter for total files in Folder
          int Count = 0;
          int totalMoved = 0;

          FileInfo[] fileNames;
          DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(rootPath);

          //set all file names as a string from network directory into an array  
          fileNames = di.GetFiles("*.*");
          Count = fileNames.Length;

          //Count = 0;//just to test exception handling

          //if no files exist in network folder throw error message.
          if (Count == 0)
          {
             fileNamesNOTmoved = "No Files Were In Directory to Move."; 
          }
          else //files exist in network folder
          {
             int delimIndex = 0;
             string folderName;
             for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
             {
                if (fileNames[i].ToString().Contains(delimeter))
                {
                   delimIndex = fileNames[i].ToString().IndexOf(delimeter);
                   folderName = fileNames[i].ToString().Substring(0, delimIndex);
                   //if folder doesnt exist create it here.
                   folderCreation(rootPath, folderName);
                   if (!File.Exists(rootPath + @"\" + folderName + @"\" + fileNames[i].Name))
                   {
                      File.Move(rootPath + @"\" + fileNames[i].ToString(), rootPath + @"\" + folderName + @"\" + fileNames[i].Name);
                      filesMoved++;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                      if (fileNamesNOTmoved == "")
                         fileNamesNOTmoved += "| ";
                      fileNamesNOTmoved += fileNames[i].Name + " | ";
                      filesNOTmoved++;
                   }
                   totalMoved++;
                }
             }
          } 
          return totalMoved;
       }

       //if folder does not exist this method will create it
       private static void folderCreation(string strTempPath, string folderName)
       {
          strTempPath = strTempPath + @"\" + folderName;
          if (!Directory.Exists(strTempPath))
          {
             //Create \folderName
             Directory.CreateDirectory(strTempPath);
             foldersCreated++;
          }
       }

       //adds entries to the log.txt file
       public static void Log(object[] details, TextWriter w)
       {
          w.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
          w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
          w.WriteLine("  :");
          w.WriteLine("  :{0}", "Files Moved = " + details[0].ToString());
          w.WriteLine("  :{0}", "Folders Created = " + details[3].ToString());
          w.WriteLine("  :{0}", "Files Not Moved = " + details[1].ToString());
          w.WriteLine("  :{0}", "Files Names Not Moved = {" + details[2].ToString() + "}");
          w.WriteLine("  :{0}", "Error Message = " + details[4].ToString());
          w.WriteLine("  :{0}", "Error Stack Trace = " + details[5].ToString());
          w.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
       }

       public static void DumpLog(StreamReader r)
       {
          string line;
          while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
          {
             Console.WriteLine(line);
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Basically would like the email to say:

1. Subject: Data Management Error Notification
2. Body: This is an Auto-Generated email to notify you there 
   was an error attempting to clean up the Files in the Directory.
   Please refer to Attached Log.txt File for more detailed information.
3. Attachment: Log.txt

Comment: You can use log4net to send emails.

Comment: log4net looks like its a great solution although it does not fit my needs.  I am looking for "Simple" email implementation not an entire new way to do the logging.  The logging I have is sufficient for the processes I need to watch.  But will +1 you for the good idea. May use it in future apps!!

Comment: So what's your question? Looks to me like you need a [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: My question is Not only what is the easiest and most simple way to implement emails but also an example on how to do so.  I like the sound of the SMTPClient but still a little unsure how to use it.  If you could post an example to help me get started I would appreciate it.

Comment: @SteveAnselment - actually if you scroll right down on the article that Jim linked to, there is a very simple example of how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out SMTP was the way to go and Due to restrictions on my local machine I could only access it from the Dev, Qua, & Prd Servers.  Once tested as admin from any of those locations.. email sent perfectly!!!

using the App.Config to hold all my To's, Froms, and the SMTP Host info and passing HTML as a string object into the method, here is the method I used to send email.

```
    public static void sendMail(string msg)
    {
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
        smtpClient.Host = smtpHost;
        message.From = fromAddress;
        message.Subject = "Test Email";
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = msg;
        message.To.Add(emailTo);
        message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        smtpClient.Send(message);
    }
```